# How to search multiple post title in wp query

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

I trying to fetch wp query using multiple post title but post title or s accept only one parameter.

This is my code:

```
$post_title = array(
'book', 
 'car',
 'bike'
);

         $conditions = array( 
              'posts_per_page' => 9, 
              'paged' => $paged,   
              'post_type'   =>'custom',
              'order'            => 'DESC',
              's' => $post_title,
              'post_status' => "publish", 

            );


        $the_query = new WP_Query( $conditions );
```

Comment: WP_Query accepts a string of single keywords joined with a '+' character. Try this: "s" => "book+car+bike",

Comment: Checked @KrunalBhimajiyani ,But its returning empty !

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to ask `WP_Query` to search for multiple post titles. Your array-valued `s` parameter looks for titles with all three words in them.

If you happen to know the posts' slugs (`$post->name` values) you can use

```php
   'post_name__in' => array ( 'book', 'car', 'bike' ),
```

to search for them. But it's hard to predict the values of slugs from post names.

Another possibility: use multiple separate WP_Query operations, one for each title, and fetch the post `ID` values for the posts. Then use

```php
   'post__in' => array (id, id, id, id),
```

to construct a WP_Query that will fetch the matching posts.

Answer (score 0):

```
$post_title = array(
    'book', 
    'car',
    'bike'
);

$multiple_title = array(); // array for store multiple arguments for multiple title

foreach ( $post_title as $title ){
    $multiple_title[] = array(
        'key' => 'title',
        'value' => $title,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
}
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post', // or 'page', or a custom post type
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // Retrieves all matching posts
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        $multiple_title,
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->have_posts()) {
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        // Display your posts here
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```